# Ruby dependency issue on MacOSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to get started with the excellent deliver tool (https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) but I know nothing about ruby. So when I try to run deliver init and I get this message, I don't know what to do about it:

```
/Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2052:in `raise_if_conflicts': can't activate json-1.6.8, already activated json-1.8.1 (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1262:in `activate'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:96:in `block in require'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:95:in `each'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:95:in `require'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/deliver-0.3.6/lib/deliver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/deliver-0.3.6/bin/deliver:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/deliver:23:in `load'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/deliver:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/sarbogast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What should I do? By the way I'm on MacOSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bundler and you have a Gemfile you can try to run it with bundle using:

```
bundle exec deliver init
```

In that way Gemfile will pick for you the right version of the json gem.

If you aren't using bundler you should uninstall the newer version of json using:

```
gem uninstall json
```

and choosing the 1.8.1 to uninstall. Then you can try to run again `deliver init`

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, all I had to do was to install json with "sudo gem install json" and it solved my problem.